# C String concatenation issue function

Tags: c, visual-c++, cstring

I'm kind of in a situation where I need to do some C-String concatenation, so I decided to take it upon my self to learn ( this is just a personal project so I have all the time in the world, really ).

So far I've come up with these two functions (explanation given below):

```
static inline  // make inline to leave out the stack manipulation
size_t StrLength( const char* string )
{
    return strnlen( string, strlen( string ) );
}

static void concatstr( char** dest, const char** src )
{
    const size_t destlen = StrLength( *dest );
    const size_t srclen  = StrLength( *src );

    const size_t total_len    = destlen + srclen; 

    const size_t totalLenNull = total_len + 1;

    char* tmp = ( char* )malloc( sizeof( char ) * totalLenNull ); //<-- Because of this...

    size_t counter = 0;

    for( size_t iDest = 0; iDest < destlen; ++iDest )
        tmp[ counter++ ] = *dest[ iDest ];

    for ( size_t iSrc = 0; iSrc < srclen; ++iSrc ) 
        tmp[ counter++ ] = *src[ iSrc ];

    *dest = ( char* ) realloc( *dest, totalLenNull ); 

    strncpy( *dest, tmp, total_len ); 

    free( tmp );

    tmp = NULL;
}
```

The idea behind the inline StrLength function is that, if I understand inline correctly, it's supposed to work like a safer macro in C++, so it's less bug prone (I think). I made it inline since it's just one line of code, and a stack manipulation for that kind of a process seems a bit much. If I'm wrong, however, please correct me on this.

Now, onto the `concatstr()` function:

The problem here is that as soon as I get to the second loop, the program crashes upon the 2nd iteration due to a memory read violation. Why this is happening I'm not sure.

The calling code looks as follows:

```
const size_t len = StrLength( msg ) + mPrefix.length() + StrLength( "\n\n" );

char* out = ( char* )malloc( sizeof( char ) * ( len + 1 ) );

out[0] = '\0';

const char* tmp_pass = mPrefix.c_str();

concatstr( &out, &tmp_pass );
concatstr( &out, &msg );
```

The only reason I'm putting a visual-C++ tag here is that even though I'm doing this like one would in straight c, I'm using VC++ as a compiler.

Does anyone have an idea of what the issue is here?

Comment: You don't need `StrLength()`; especially after reading the code of that function; use `strlen()` directly. Please see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence. `[]` takes precedence over `*` and you use that in 2 places.

Answer (score 2):

You have the precedences wrong,

```
tmp[ counter++ ] = *dest[ iDest ];
```

is (implicitly) parethesised

```
tmp[ counter++ ] = *(dest[ iDest ]);
```

but you need

```
tmp[ counter++ ] = (*dest)[ iDest ];
```

with explicit parentheses.

Without the parentheses, the (presumed) `char*` at an offset of `iDest * sizeof(char*)` bytes after `*dest` is dereferenced, there probably isn't a valid `char*` that you are allowed to dereference. You want to access the byte at an offset of `iDest` bytes after what `*dest` points to.

At the end,

```
strncpy( *dest, tmp, total_len );
```

doesn't 0-terminate the concatenated strings. You need `totalLenNull` there.

Aside:

```
return strnlen( string, strlen( string ) );
```

is rather circumspect. First you traverse `string` to find the terminating 0-byte, counting `char`s before that. Then you check whether there is a terminating 0-byte among the first `strlen(string)` bytes of `string`. Unless `string` is modified between these two calls (and then you're probably hosed), the second will return exactly the same as the first call.